# Array formula for a rolling AVERAGEIF formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a working formula that I need to drag to autofill down a column and want to make it into an array formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()), ">=0",INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()))
```

So if you put this formula in column B it will take the values in column A and continually average them going down, skipping any values that are less than 0. Here is an example screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj0ar.png

How can I make an array formula for this?

---

This formula comes close but I couldn't figure out how to add the ">=0" conditional:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),SUMIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:A)/COUNTIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),))
```

Comment: I can demo a way to do it if you make your spreadsheet editable instead of just view only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Lambda Update

There is no longer any need to use `ArrayFormula` for this.

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),
  LAMBDA(rowOff,
    AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(A2,0,0,rowOff),">=0"))
)
```

#### How?

- For each element `rowOff` in 1..`# items in column`:

  - Use `AverageIf` to get the average of everything starting at the top taking `rowOff` rows, excluding everything `>=0`

---

### Old solution

Here's a single formula that can go into B2 (no need to drag), but it's fairly complicated:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2:A),MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A),1,2)<=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A),1,2)))*FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A))),--(FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A))>0))/COUNTIFS(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),"<="&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)),">=0"),"")))
```

#### Readable:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(
    IF(
        LEN(A2:A),
        MMULT(
            TRANSPOSE(
                (SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A),1,2)<=
                    TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A),1,2))
                )*FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A))
            ),
            --(FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A))>0)
        )/
        COUNTIFS(
            SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),
            "<="&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),
            FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)),
            ">=0"
        ),
        ""
    )
))
```

#### How?

1. We can achieve a running sum using `MMULT` on a Lower Triangular Matrix of size `COUNTA(A2:A)` of all 1's and all non blanks of `A2:A`, which we filter out if the number is negative. In this case, it produces `{2;2;6;6;6;6}`.
2. The `COUNTIFS()` produces an array of the number of elements we want to divide by. Here, it's `{1;1;2;2;3;4}`
3. Then ignore any blanks at the with `IF`.
4. Blank out any errors with `IFERROR`. (`#DIV/0!` errors can happen if the leading numbers are negative.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this formula can help:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IF($A$2:A2>=0,$A$2:A2,"")))
```

[image]